# Use monit to monitor a java program

Tags: java, monit

I am writing to get some help regarding starting my java programs via Monit. I have written a start script program.sh. The monit code and the scipt code is given with this posting.

The issue is that I am not able the start and stop the program using the the script file executed via monit. I can monitor the process if I start it using the terminal but I can't start/stop it with monit. The log from monit says "Failed to start"

However, I can start and stop programs like ssh easliy from monit. The monit runs under sudo and I am running the scripts from an account with administrative privileges.
It will very helpful if someone helps me figure this out
Thanks

monitrc file

```
#++++++++++#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#Monit settings
set daemon 10 with start delay 2            # check services at 2-minute intervals
set logfile syslog facility log_daemon                      
set logfile /var/log/monit.log
set idfile /var/lib/monit/id
set statefile /var/lib/monit/state
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
# Mail Server
set mailserver smtp.gmail.com port 587
    username "monit.abc123@gmail.com" password "password"
    using tlsv1 with timeout 30 seconds

set eventqueue
      basedir /var/lib/monit/events # set the base directory where events will be stored
      slots 100                     # optionally limit the queue size


set alert abc123@gmail.com                       # receive all alerts
set alert abc123@gmail.com only on { timeout }   # receive just service-
#                                                # timeout alert
#set alert foo@bar { nonexist, timeout, resource, icmp, connection }
#set alert security@bar on { checksum, permission, uid, gid }
# setup the email for the SMS thing over here.......................
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
set httpd port 2813 and
#     use address localhost  # only accept connection from localhost
     allow localhost        # allow localhost to connect to the server and
     allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
     allow admin:monit      # require user 'admin' with password 'monit'
#    allow @monit           # allow users of group 'monit' to connect (rw)
#    allow @users readonly  # allow users of group 'users' to connect readonly
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
set mail-format {
    from: monit@$HOST
    subject: Monit Alert --  $EVENT $SERVICE
    message: $EVENT Service $SERVICE
                 Date:        $DATE
                 Action:      $ACTION
                 Host:        $HOST
                 Description: $DESCRIPTION

            Your faithful employee,
            Monit
}
#+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

#***********************************************************************************************
#Computer Resources check
check system myhost.mydomain.tld
    if loadavg (1min) > 4 for 5 cycles then alert
    if loadavg (5min) > 2 for 5 cycles then alert
    if memory usage > 75% for 3 cycles then alert
    if swap usage > 25% for 5 cycles then alert
    if cpu usage (user) > 70% for 5 cycles then alert
    if cpu usage (system) > 70% for 5 cycles then alert
    if cpu usage (wait) > 20% for 5 cycles then alert
#***********************************************************************************************


################################################################################################
#Monitoring SSH Service

check process ssh123 with pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/ssh start"
stop program = "/etc/init.d/ssh stop"
if cpu > 50% for 5 cycles then alert
if totalmem > 200 MB for 5 cycles then alert
if children > 2 then alert
#if loadavg(5min) greater than 10 for 8 cycles then stop
#if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout

################################################################################################
#Monitoring Prorgam in Java

check process javaprg with pidfile /home/user/Desktop/Binaries/javaprg.pid
start program = "/home/user/Desktop/Binaries/javaprg.sh start"
stop program = "/home/user/Desktop/Binaries/javaprg.sh stop"  
if cpu > 50% for 5 cycles then alert
if totalmem > 1500 MB for 5 cycles then alert
if children > 2 then alert
#if loadavg(5min) greater than 10 for 8 cycles then stop
#if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

Start/Stop script

```
#!/bin/bash
 case $1 in
    start)
       echo $$ > javaprg.pid;
       exec /usr/bin/java -jar javaprg.jar
       ;;
     stop) 
       kill $(cat javaprg.pid);
       rm javaprg.pid
       ;;
     *) 
       echo "usage: javaprg {start|stop}" ;;
 esac
 exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set absolute path in your start stop script.

You can try to launch it using a rooted shell `sudo -s`.

And you should concider using the `/etc/monit/conf.d` folder to put your conf files.

Comment: Managed to make it work with absolute paths. Sorry for the super late answer acceptance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was trying to configure a shell script under Monit.
what solved the problem was using the /bin/sh prior to the program itself.

try using:

`start program = "/home/user/Desktop/Binaries/javaprg.sh start"`

`stop program = "/home/user/Desktop/Binaries/javaprg.sh stop"`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using your script, and it was because the start script did not specify where to save the PID. It was saving javaprg.pid to / rather then the home folder. Change start script to `'echo $$ > /home/usr/binaries/javaprg.pid'` and it will work.