# How to check if a process is running on a client's computer (on server-side)? [Java]

Tags: java, process, ip, client, port

So, how can I check if a process is running in Java?

I'm running a private server of some game...

And I got the player's IP and the port that they are using to connect..

Thanks in-advance.

EDIT:

I am using Windows 7, and again, I need to get the client's processes information

and then determine if the process is running or not, and not my server's computer

processes.. :/

any ideas?? :(

Comment: I think this is a relevant post => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316553/use-monit-to-monitor-a-java-program

Comment: Put quite frankly there is no easy platform neutral way to do it so you may want to list your OS details...

Comment: Also somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Windows 7, sorry forgot to mention.. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -e");
```

Then use proc.getInputStream() to read the output of the command.

BTW the above command is for linux

for windows I believe the command is "tasklist"

Answer (score -1):

You can use the wmic utility to check the list of running processes.
Suppose you want to check if the windows' explorer.exe process is running :

```
        String line;
        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic.exe");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            OutputStreamWriter oStream = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
            oStream .write("process where name='explorer.exe'");
            oStream .flush();
            oStream .close();
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

See http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html or http://support.microsoft.com/servicedesks/webcasts/wc072402/listofsampleusage.asp for some example of what you can get from wmic...

Comment: You are assuming that the OP is running windows which nay not be the case.